# In Latex, how to increase the size the font coloring when writing mathematical mode

Tags: formatting

I would like to write color equations and increase the font

Comment: We would like to have a MWE.Period!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
{\LARGE\color{red}
\begin{equation}
y = x^2
\end{equation}
}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you **always** wanted the `equation` environment to be `\LARGE` and `red`, then you could save a few keystrokes in the long run with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\LARGE\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
y = x^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```