# Changing text font size without changing math font size

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I want to change font size of text to 14pt, but it's important to me that math font size must be 12pt.

Is there any way to change font size of text without changing font size of math text?

I would grateful for any help.

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235877/in-latex-how-to-increase-the-size-the-font-coloring-when-writing-mathematical-m

Comment: @Oiale Could you please accept my answer given below? It's been more than a year now and no one else seem to have posted anything better ... Thanks!

Comment: @Oiale Cheers mate! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the surrounding text font size to `14pt` by normal means. And to maintain the math font size to `12pt` you could use the `\DeclareMathSizes` in your preamble. The syntax is:

```
\DeclareMathSizes{display size}{text size}{script size}{scriptscript size}
```

So, for instance, you could set:

```
\DeclareMathSizes{14pt}{12pt}{10pt}{8pt}
```

Or make all math sizes equal:

```
\DeclareMathSizes{14pt}{12pt}{12pt}{12pt}
```

It really depends on your requirements! But adding either code to your document's preamble should achieve what you needed to do.

Reference: [@Stephan Kottwitz's answer shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5152/78565)

Comment: I would have chosen `\DeclareMathSizes{12pt}{12pt}{8pt}{6pt}`.